# Weird HTML issue after inspecting the element

Tags: html

I am having a weird issue with my HTML. It is almost like it is being escaped for some reason. The problem is on my  tag, it is being rendered as:

```
<h3&nbsp;class="custom-image-text">Student Stories
                </h3&nbsp;class="custom-image-text">
```

I was trying out bracket editor (usually use sublime) but I don't think the editor was the problem. Also tried it on JSFiddle and get the same result (when you inspect the element). I will add my code in the snippet but if it doesn't do it there I will link to a JSFiddle, any idea what is happening? Also I will add I did 'cat' the file and the HTML was clean on the  tag as I would expect

```html
            <div class="custom-image-container">
                <img class="front-page-flex-image" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/startup.jpg'; ?>" />
                <div class="custom-image-overlay">
                    <h3 class="custom-image-text">Student Stories</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You *have* tried simply re-typing that tag to ensure there are no weird characters? Also, *where exactly* do you see it "rendered" like that?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, on my inspector is working as expected. please post a fiddle to reproduce the issue

Comment: I have tried retyping it but can try again. Maybe it is just something with my browser. I can post the fiddle but it IS happening for me in the SO snippet so if its not happening for you there it probably wont happen in the fiddle.

Comment: Also, right click on the "student stories" text, then inspect element, but also click edit as HTML because that is where I see it. It looks normal when just inspecting but not showing up as an H3

Comment: So, when using the DOM inspector of your browser and choosing *edit as HTML* is the only place you see that? Then I'd stop worrying about it and chalk it up to a browser peculiarity, not an actual issue with your code.

Comment: Well the problem is that it is ignoring both the class and the type of element (not applying the CSS). If in the "edit as html" I clean it up to how it should be on the H3 tag then the CSS becomes active on it.

Comment: No idea why but it is working now.....Tried re-writing a bigger section and it is now working

Answer (score -1):

Problem is that your HTML code contains also PHP. You need to process that code by PHP, which will return HTML.